# ASP.NET register button from identity throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I added Indentity to my web app and wanted to click added ,,Register" while running it, however one particular error ruined it for me:

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Orchard.Entities.User]' while attempting to activate 'Orchard.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'`

This is code for User Entity:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Orchard.Entities
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public override string Id { get; set; }
        public string NickName { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public List<Messages> Messages { get; set; } = new List<Messages>();

    }
}
```

What is wrong with it?

I tried this with ,,User" and ,,IdentityUser" and it seems to work only with IdentityUser, but I have no Idea how it works:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<OrchardDBContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[Orchard.Entities.User]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Orchard.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'`

From your error message, I guess you have used   `private SignInManager<User> signInManager;` in your Orchard.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel, but you  register `AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>`

Try to register like:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<OrchardDBContext>();
```

Comment: Thank you sir. After a few changes and your solution it works :)